# how to force stop a task

Tags: c#, task

As a title I need to force stop a task, I have tried with tokenSource but unfortunally not work... :(

this is my code:

```
        public Task StartAsync()
       {
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _token = _tokenSource.Token;
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            do
            {                                
                Reset();
                try
                {                        
                    DoWorkAsync().Wait();                        
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    Dictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    properties.Add("descrizione", "Eccezione gestita esternamente!");
                    RegisterExceptionsAsync(e, properties).Wait();
                }

                PrintMatches();
                RegisterSummaryAsync().Wait();

                if (!_stop)
                {                     
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(_options.LapTimeout);                      
                }
            }
            while (!_stop);


        }, _token);
    }   

    public void Stop()
    {
        _stop = true;
    }

    public void ForceStop()
    {
        _tokenSource.Cancel(false);
        WatchTime.Stop();
    }
```

When in Main function I call ForceStop() method, the task does not stopped but is continuosly in running status... Any idea?
thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't force a task to stop. Tasks use cooperative cancelling, so you can only ask which is what CancellationTokenSource.Cancel is doing. The task itself must regularly check if a cancellation was requested by calling CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested. For this to properly work the CancellationToken should also be provided to called async methods like DoWorkAsync and RegisterExceptionsAsync, which would also need to check for cancellation.

Comment: Also don't use Task.Wait(), Task.Result or Thread.Sleep in Tasks. Use the asynchronous versions thereof, i.e. instead of "Task.Run(() =>" write "Task.Run(async () =>" and then "await DoWorkAsync()", "await RegisterExceptionsAsync(...)", "await Task.Delay(_options.LapTimeout, _token)". The latter also has the advantage that if cancellation is requested it will immediately stop instead of just sleeping further.